# I can't change max_input_vars effectively

Tags: php

I'm trying to translate some categories on prestashop 1.6 using php 5.6.
It says the limit of max_input_vars is set to 1000 and that I need to contact godaddy and pay them 40 euros to change it.

(okay it doesn't say that about the money, I added that after contacting their web support :P)

I was wondering if I could do it myself.

I created my own php.ini and put it on public_html

```
post_max_size = 20000M
upload_max_filesize = 20000M
max_execution_time = 30000
max_input_time = 60000
memory_limit = 8000M
max_input_vars = 8000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 8000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 8000
```

No dice.
Then I put the following lines in .htdocs file

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/vasilonet/php.ini
</IfModule>
```

Still nothing. The website refuses to allow me to do translations. It still says the limit is 1000.

I haven't even begun using my website and all these php limitations are really bizarre. What's with the small limits? (e.g. 8MB import limit for mysql files, etc)

Comment: Did you restart the apache after changing configuration?

Comment: You know, this is really odd but I don't think my shared hosting account is allowed to do that. -.- I'll contact them , and they will probably ask for another 40 euros lol

Comment: Probably you need a dedicated VM

Comment: You know what, that's it. But even if I did that, then something else would pop up. And then something else. So I'm gonna stick with one language for now.  Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The following **will only work** if your php.ini allows you to overwrite the settings.

Based on your question, add these lines to your .htaccess file:

```
php_value post_max_size = 20000M
php_value upload_max_filesize = 20000M
php_value max_execution_time = 30000
php_value max_input_time = 60000
php_value memory_limit = 8000M
php_value max_input_vars = 8000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars = 8000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars = 8000
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my latest experience you should check this php manual link:

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

You just have to place one

> .user.ini

to the main shop folder and one into the admin folder.

After this you should restart the php/apache service

Comment: Have you tried adding the file without the restart?

Regarding to this it should work without the restart as well:
[link https://uk.godaddy.com](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/phpiniuserini-changes-not-taking-effect-5647)
 
 
`memory_limit = 256M;`
`max_execution_time=44000;`
`max_input_time=-1;`
`upload_max_filesize=25M;`
`post_max_size=20M;`
`max_input_vars=10000;`
`suhosin.get.max_vars = 10000;`
`suhosin.post.max_vars = 10000;`

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem while setting up Uncode Wordpress template. I tried increasing `max_input_vars` to 3000 in `.htaccess`, `.user.ini` and even `php.ini` of the server. However, the `PHP Max Input Vars (allowed)` was 999 and highlighted in red. This caused us loosing all our template customization after a while. Finally I solved the issue by adding the following in the `php.ini` file of the server.

```
suhosin.post.max_vars=3001
suhosin.request.max_vars=3001
```

It need to be 3001 in order to get the Effective Max Var (PHP Max Input Vars (allowed)) to 3000 and green. I had tried adding these values to `.user.ini` and `.htaccess`, but didn't work.